# Is there a method for calculating a stacked subtracted and summed tier in Power Pivot (DAX)

Tags: dax, powerpivot, tiers

[image: Power Pivot DAX question on stacked subtracted and summed tiers]

Column `W` gives a simple explanation on how it should be calculated for quantity `500.`. For a normal stack tier I have a working DAX formula below. However, that does not work for a stacked subtracted and summed tier.

```
VAR _quantity = [Quantity]
VAR _year_product = Quantity2022[YearProduct]
    RETURN
        MINX(FILTER(PriceList;
            AND(_year_product=PriceList[YearProduct];_quantity>=PriceList[QFrom]));
                PriceList[Price]*[Quantity]))
```

How can I do the same for a stacked tier?

Comment: How did you get quantity `500`?

Comment: Quantity 500 is just a number to use for calculating the price